# Copying contents of a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

If there exists an old data of a model say ,

```
query=Emp.objects.filter(pk=profile.id)
```

Is there a easier way to copy the same values into the same model again..

Now that the id will be different so..

I have this requirement.

Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
object = Emp.objects.get(pk=profile.id)
object.save(force_insert=True)
```

It's much more explicit then removing primary key's value. See also ["forcing an insert or update"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update) in Django documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a complex model with inheritance, this should work:

```
query.pk = None
query.save() #Will insert new record
```

For the other case I found a snippet [here](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1040/), did not test it however.

Comment: Sorry but i wanted the duplicate records in the same table which will have a different id since id is PK

Comment: `query` is here a `QuerySet` so `query.pk = None` won't work. Better use `.object.get` instead of `.objects.filter`

Comment: you're right, it should be get instead of filter (or you should loop over the filtered objects). And Hulk, sory but I really don't understand your question?

Comment: if there are entries like id=1,name="Tom" desg="Senior manager"
How to copy the same values into the table when now all the data remains the same except for  id

Comment: well, do as I say, but you only have to make sure the 'query' variable of my code is a model instance (e.g. you got by calling .get() or iterating over a queryset). setting pk to None and calling the save method will make sure the object will be duplicated with a new id.